# How to format a pivot like table that includes records for all time and id values?

Tags: r, reshape

I'm collecting logs in R with 3 columns:
week, probe, and number of observations.
There aren't record when there is no observation.

```
week=c(1,2,2,4)  
probe=c("A","C","B","C")  
obs=c(2,4,3,1)
logs=data.frame(week,probe,obs)

logs

week probe obs  
1     A   2
2     C   4
2     B   3
4     C   1
```

I want to reformat the data so that it includes all weeks and all probes even if there was no observation, so that it looks like this:

```
week probe obs  
1     A   2  
1     B   0  
1     C   0  
1     D   0  
2     A   0  
2     B   0  
2     C   3  
2     D   4  
3     A   0  
3     B   0  
3     C   0  
3     D   0  
4     A   0  
4     B   0  
4     C   1  
4     D   0
```

I have the list of all probes here:

```
allprobes=c("A","B","C","D")
```

and I want to look at these weeks:

```
allweeks=c(1:4)
```

I've been looking at melt, cast, reshape, but I only manage to get 1 line per id or month... 
as I actually want to keep the original format of the logs. 
It seems easy enough at first but I'm now stuck...
Any advice on how to get the data formatted this way?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two options in base R:

#### Use `expand.grid` and `merge`:

```
> fullFrame <- expand.grid(allweeks, allprobes)
> names(fullFrame) <- c("week", "probe")
> merge(fullFrame, logs, all = TRUE)
   week probe obs
1     1     A   2
2     1     B  NA
3     1     C  NA
4     1     D  NA
5     2     A  NA
6     2     B   3
7     2     C   4
8     2     D  NA
9     3     A  NA
10    3     B  NA
11    3     C  NA
12    3     D  NA
13    4     A  NA
14    4     B  NA
15    4     C   1
16    4     D  NA
```

`expand.grid` will create a `data.frame` of all the possible combinations of your "allprobes" and "allweeks" objects. Then, we rename the columns of that new `data.frame` to match the relevant columns from your "logs" `data.frame` when using `merge`. The argument `all = TRUE` tells `merge` to fill in the missing values with `NA`.

If you want zeroes instead of `NA`, proceed as follows:

```
fullFrame <- expand.grid(allweeks, allprobes)
names(fullFrame) <- c("week", "probe")
finalLogs <- merge(fullFrame, logs, all = TRUE)
finalLogs[is.na(finalLogs)] <- 0
```

#### Use `xtabs` after converting "week" and "probe" to factors

If you convert "week" and "probe" to factors that includes all the relevant levels, then you can simply use `xtabs` wrapped in `data.frame`:

```
logs$week <- factor(logs$week, levels=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
logs$probe <- factor(logs$probe, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
data.frame(xtabs(obs ~ week + probe, logs))
#    week probe Freq
# 1     1     A    2
# 2     2     A    0
# 3     3     A    0
# 4     4     A    0
# 5     1     B    0
# 6     2     B    3
# 7     3     B    0
# 8     4     B    0
# 9     1     C    0
# 10    2     C    4
# 11    3     C    0
# 12    4     C    1
# 13    1     D    0
# 14    2     D    0
# 15    3     D    0
# 16    4     D    0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `complete` function in the `tidyr` package is a nice utility for this operation:

```
# get all the levels in the factor
logs$probe = factor(logs$probe, levels = allprobes)
logs$week = factor(logs$week, levels = 1:4)

tidyr::complete(logs, week, probe, fill = list(obs = 0))
# # A tibble: 16 × 3
#      week  probe   obs
#    <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
# 1       1      A     2
# 2       1      B     0
# 3       1      C     0
# 4       1      D     0
# 5       2      A     0
# 6       2      B     3
# 7       2      C     4
# 8       2      D     0
# 9       3      A     0
# 10      3      B     0
# 11      3      C     0
# 12      3      D     0
# 13      4      A     0
# 14      4      B     0
# 15      4      C     1
# 16      4      D     0
```